# Accessing yield inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Since it it not possible to create a arrow generator function,
`yield` is never used in the context of an arrow function.

```
var arrowGenerator = *() => { };
```

You should be able to use **yield** in the context of the generator function, like this:

```
function* generator() {
    funcWithCallback((value) => {
       yield value;
    });
}
```

but in babel it uses `yield` in context of the arrow function and not the generators.

I want to do this so you don't need to return a callback function with the value, just to yield it.

```
function* gen() {
    yield function (callback) {
        funcWithCallback(callback);
    } 
}
```

How can I yield from this nested function?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can't. You can only use `yield` directly in the body of a generator function.

Comment: What would you expect `func` to do with that function? You cannot yield across functions. Also, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your example can be simplified to `function* gen() { yield funcWithCallback; }` - and even in there, you are not `yield`ing from inside the callback.

Comment: I think this is a valuable question which highlights a misunderstanding which could be resolved with a useful answer. It's a shame it's closed. I came here because I was trying to `yield` from within an arrow function passed to a `forEach()` within my generator function. The answer for me was to change from `y.forEach(x => yield transform(x))` to f`or (const x of y) { yield transform(x) }`

Comment: @br3nt The problem with the question is that it doesn't ask a question.

Comment: @mark The question is very obvious: "How do I yield from within a nested scope?".  Just because there is no ? doesn't mean there isn't a question.  The user clearly understands and demonstrates what they want to do and therefore they are clearly asking for help with what pattern to use to get the results they want instead of what they know doesn't work.

Comment: As to an actual answer for this question: if `funcWithCallback` was changed to a generator, then the calling code could be changed to `yield* funcWithCallback(value => { yield value; })`.

Comment: @br3nt Even "obvious" questions need to be stated explicitly, because what you say is obviously the question is not so obvious to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `yield` and `yield*` keywords can only be used ***directly*** inside a generator function. Your code fragment is conceptually flawed in a similar manner to:

```
function f1() {
  if(someCondition) {
    f2((value) => {
       else {
         // do something
       }
    });
  }
}
```

or, to this:

```
function f1() {
  f2((value) => {
    return someValue; // while this is legal, it doesn't cause f1 to return
  });

  codeAfterReturn();
}
```

Obviously, these 2 examples don't "work", and so does your code fragment.

Comment: but when you yield, you are not returning the function and ending executing of the function, you suspend it. and then it should be possible right?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. That's the specification of the language / syntax. It's not an opinion and my examples above demonstrate the kind of mistake in your attempt

Comment: okay thanks for clearing it up. :)