# js generator for asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, socket.io, generator, ecmascript-6

How to use yield in a nested function?

```
function* translate(){
    socket.once( 'translate/set', function( data){
        yield data
    });

    socket.emit( 'translate/get', { query: query})
};


var data = translate().next().value;
console.log( data);
```

Error

```
yield is not defined
```

I do not understand how to use the generator to an asynchronous function, without changing their code

Comment: Calling `.next` on a generator synchronously yields a value. That makes it impossible to support this workflow.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? [You cannot yield from within a non-generator function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32342448/1048572) (such as a callback). But why are you using a generator at all?

Comment: I want to asynchronously load the translation and return it to the synchronous style.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `yield` outside of a generator's *immediate* inner context. What you can do however is pass a callback to `translate`, yield the call to `socket.once` (giving it the callback), and then continue execution of `translate` once this callback is invoked.

```
function* translate(cb){
    yield socket.once('translate/set', cb);
    socket.emit('translate/get', {query: query})
}

var translate = translate(cb);
translate().next(); // ...socket#once

function cb(data) {
    console.log(data); // data from socket#once
    translate.next(); // ...socket#emit
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but data is still in the callback.

Comment: There is no way around that.